# IE Javascript SCRIPT5007

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

Starting getting this error when trying to delete product in IE. I have fixed the first part of the problem which was JSON was undefined, so I src'd a json2.js. But now I am getting a SCRIPT5007 error. Would appreciate some help!

```
function ProductDelete(MenuboardProducts) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ProductBooks.aspx/DeleteProduct",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ MenuboardProduct: MenuboardProducts }),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(ret) {
                    if (ret.d) {
                        alert(ret.d);
                        $find("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadAjaxPanel1").ajaxRequest();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

ERROR ::: SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'ProductDelete' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Here is the back-end code:

```
OutID = Convert.ToInt32(drpOutletL.SelectedValue);
                        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                        var js = serializer.Serialize(lstMenuboardProductsInUse);
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),
                            "Delete", "if(confirm('" + sb.ToString() + "')){ProductDelete(" + js + ");}", true);
```

Comment: PLease provide more information on how the error occurs. Does it happen when you call the function 'ProductDelete()?

Comment: Hi David, yes it happens when i call the function in an aspx page. it works in chrome and firefox, but in IE it just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Took away the Json reference, and set my meta compatibility to ie=7, ie=9 in the master file.